# Applying appendTo for adding a sort node to apply-template

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt, append

I am trying to programmtically insert an appendTo() method with jquery. I have a formatting stylesheet which formats an xml sheet, but I do it in a third HTML document using jquery and javascript. My original xml is in this format:

```
<guitars>
    <guitar>
        <model>AStrat</model>
        <year>1978</year>
        <name>Strat</name>
        <price>2500</price>
    </guitar>
</guitars>
```

and my stylesheet is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table id="guitarTable" border="1" width="200">
            <tr class="header">
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/guitars/guitar">
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="guitar">
        <tr>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="model" /> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="year" />  </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="name"/> </td>
            <td> <xsl:value-of select="price" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is my javascript. `stylesheet` is the stylesheet above imported via ajax and I've checked works correctly.

```
var nodeToAppend = '<xsl:sort select="model" data-type="text"/>'
$(nodeToAppend).appendTo( $(stylesheet)
                              .find("xsl\\:apply-templates, apply-templates")
                              .first() );
```

But this doesn't seem to want to take. Later on, I apply the XSL to the XML via an XSLT processor. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Basically I want this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/guitars/guitar">
                </xsl:apply-templates>
```

to become:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/guitars/guitar">
          <xsl:sort select="model" data-type="text"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define a global parameter `<xsl:param name="sort-key"/>` in the XSLT and then have

```
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/guitars/guitar">
          <xsl:sort select="*[local-name() = $sort-key]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
```

then, instead of manipulating the XSLT code each time you need to change that key, you would simply set the parameter differently e.g. given `var proc = new XSLTProcessor();` with an imported stylesheet you can then set e.g. `proc.setParameter('', 'sort-key', 'model');` before running the next transformation. There is no need to manipulate the XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that would work. Unfortunately due to my requirements I was forced to get my result by dynamically altering the XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT**

```
      <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
          <table id="guitarTable" border="1" width="200">
              <tr class="header">
                  <th>Model</th>
                  <th>Year</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
              </tr>
              <div id="append_here">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="/guitars/guitar">
              </xsl:apply-templates>
              </div>
          </table>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="guitar">
          <tr>
              <td> <xsl:value-of select="model" /> </td>
              <td> <xsl:value-of select="year" />  </td>
              <td> <xsl:value-of select="name"/> </td>
              <td> <xsl:value-of select="price" /> </td>
          </tr>
      </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**jquery**

```
//<xsl:apply-templates><![CDATA[
  $(function() {
    $("div#append_here" ).children().append('<xsl:sort select="model" data-type="text"/>');
  });
//]]></xsl:apply-templates>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vcrchyyt/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not doing it. I think the problem may be this `$("div#append_here" )`  . Both in your version and mine, the jquery isn't successfully targeting the external xsl document.

Comment: I did find a hack around it. Unfortunately it doesn't involve any of the `append`  methods. In the original xsl sheet, I have this:

`<xsl:apply-templates select="/guitars/guitar">
          <xsl:sort select="nothing" data-type="text"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>` and then I simply am using this in my html page:

`$(stylesheet).find("xsl\\:sort, sort").first().attr("select", sortByElement);` where `sortByElement = ` model, year, price, etc.